# Android onCreate ClassCastException

Tags: android, xml, inflate

I have this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.main, null);
    setContentView(layout);
    s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
```

It throws a `ClassCastException` why is it?
If I do `setContentView(R.layout.main)` everything goes well. But i need to have the layout in a variable because I need it to use an advertsiment library. Is there a a way to inflate the XML and have the layout in an variable?

Thanks

Comment: is root element of `main.xml` actually a `LinearLayout`?

Comment: yes it is the line which throws the exception is the last line of the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which line is throwing the ClassCastException?

Also you can use `setContentView(R.layout.main);` then still use a normal find view by id call to get a reference to your root layout.

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.yourParentId);
```

as long as this comes after you've called setContentView() you should get returned a reference to your layout object that you can use however you wish.

Comment: thats what i was looking for thanks, the error persists but i think i have somethign wrong out of this file, because i have put this with setcontentview and i it persists, if i found the erro i will tell you , thanks to everybody.

Comment: i solved the problem, no idea what it was. Just had to delete and rewrite the this piece of code and everything went well.wtf?!

Comment: occasionally you'll find odd errors like that. It is worth it to try cleaning your project with eclipse. In your package manager window right click on your project and choose "Clean selected project(s)" that will do a sort of refresh on your project and I've found that it will fix strange errors sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

On what line does it throw the exception? Maybe the root view of the layout is not really a `LinearLayout`. Or maybe `R.id.spinner1` is not a `Spinner`.